# Equation of circle orthogonal with $2$ given circles

Tags: circles, orthogonality

> Find **the minimum radius** of a circle which is orthogonal with both the circles: $C_1: x^2+y^2-12x+35=0$ and $C_2: x^2+y^2+4x+3=0$.

I know about the condition for a circle to be orthogonal to a given circle.
$$d^2 = r_1^2+r_2^2,\;\text{ whereas }\;d = \overline{O_1O_2}$$

I couldn't apply this in $3$ circles.
Moreover, i am unaware of the concept of radical and coaxial system.

I'll be obliged if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first given a circle $C$ of unit radius, you can draw a circle $C_{\perp}$ centred at any point $P$ outside $C$. all you need to do is draw the two tangents to $C$ from $P$ let the contact points be $T_1, T_2.$  the radius is the common value $PT_1 = PT_2$ with center $P.$

suppose you have two non intersecting circles $C_1, C_2$ of equal radius $1$ and you require a circle $C_{\perp}$ orthogonal to both. by the previous argument, the center of $C$ is equal distance, the radius of $C_{\perp}.$   that means the center $P$ of $C_{\perp}$ is on the perpendicular bisector of the centers of $C_1$
and $C_2.$ the smallest radius occurs when $P$ is the midpoint of the centers of $C_1$ and $C_2$

the midpoint of the two centers  $(6,0), (-2,0)$ of $x²+y²-12x+35=0 $ and $  x²+y²+4x+3=0$ is $(2,0)$ so the smallest radius is $$\sqrt{4^2 - 1} = \sqrt{15} $$

added later:

the reason for the above formula is that if the circle centered at $(2,0)$ has radius $r$ that is orthogonal to the circle of radius $1$ centered at $(6,0.)$ the distance between the centers is $4.$ therefore $r^2 + 1 = 4^2$

Comment: Why did we take c=1 for finding radius of the circle?

Comment: i took the radius to be $1$ because both the circles in question have radii $1.$

Comment: I still don't understand it. You found out the center to be (4,0). Now why did you subtract 1 from 4²

Comment: @user208322, i have added some more explanation. see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Alright sir, that helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the centers and the radii of $C_1$ and $C_2$. Then find where a center of a circle orthogonal to both of these circles could lie.

Answer (score -1):

Given the questions you have asked earlier, it looks like you are picking them up from fitjee RSM. But either way, to solve the question quickly, you should know the formula:

$2*(g1)*(g2) + 2*(f1)*(f2) = c1 + c2$
(where equation of circle: $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx+ 2fy + c =0$)

for first circle,
$2*(-6)*f+0=35+c$

for second circle,
$2*(2)*f=3+c$

solving, we get $f=-2$ and $c=-11$

Radius of circle is $(f^2+g^2-c)^{1/2} = (15+g^2)^{1/2}$

Now for minimum radius of circle, $g=0$, so radius = $\sqrt{15}$

---

Comment: Hi, you really should use MathJax to format your math on this site. If you don't, people will tend to ignore your posts/answers. They will pay more attention to what you write if you properly format it.

Comment: @sebastian I am actually new to this site so I still have to learn how to use math Jax formatting... But anyways, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Also, except the poor formatting what else was wrong with this post that it got a downvote?